# Name of this curve

Tags: curves, parametric

The parametrized curve $(\cos t, \sin t)$ is the circle.

The parametrized curve $(\cos t + \cos 2t, \sin t + \sin 2t)$ is the cardioid curve.

Is there a name for the curve $(\sum_{k=1}^n\cos kt, \sum_{k=1}^n\sin kt)$?

Comment: The second one is not a cardioid, it's a Limacon of Pascal I believe: it's a smooth curve (no cusp) with one crossing (two loops, a big one and a small one). The others are similar with one big loop and $n-1$ small loops, with one crossing where all the loops intersect and another crossing where all the small loops intersect. If they have a name, I don't know it.